# Optimizing Django with prefetch and filters in large table

Tags: django, django-models, query-optimization, manytomanyfield, prefetch

I had a database in php/html using MySQL and am transferring this to a Django project.

I have all the functionalities working, but loading a table of the data I want is immensely slow because of the relations with other tables.

After searching for days I know that I probably have to use a `model.Manager` to use `prefetch_all`. However, I am not stuck on how to call this into my template.

I have the following models(simplified):

```
class OrganisationManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset_director(self):
        person_query = Position.objects.select_related('person').filter(position_current=True,
            position_type="director"
            )
        return super().get_queryset().prefetch_related(Prefetch('position_set', queryset=person_query, to_attr="position_list"))
    def get_queryset_president(self):
        person_query = Position.objects.select_related('person').filter(position_current=True,
            position_type="president"
            )
        return super().get_queryset().prefetch_related(Prefetch('position_set', queryset=person_query, to_attr="position_list"))
 
class Person(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

class Organisation(models.Model):
    organisation_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    positions = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Position')

    # positions are dynamic, even though there should only be only one director and president at each given time, a onetoone model wouldn't work in this scenario
    objects =  OrganisationManager()

    # The following defs are currently used to show the names and start dates of the director and president in the detailview and listview
    def director(self):
        return self.position_set.filter(position_current=True, position_type="director").last()
    def president(self):
        return self.position_set.filter(position_current=True, position_type="P").last()

class Position(models.Model):
    POSITION_TYPES = (
        ('president','President'),
        ('director','Director'),
        )
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(Organisation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    position_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=POSITION_TYPES, blank=True, null=True)
    position_current = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    position_start = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want my table to look like this:

| Organisation Name | President | President Start Date | Director | Director Start Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Organisation 1 | President of org 1 | 2013 | Director of org 1 | 2015 |
| Organisation 2 | President of org 2 | 2018 | Director of org 2 | 2017 |

With the code I currently have, it all works great. But because it has to call the database each time, this even causes Heroku to timeout.

I don't understand how to use the prefetch query in the `models.Manager` in the table (`ListView`) template. Thanks!

Comment: You can use subqueries for this. What is `last()` defined on? Or can it be anything because there is only one president or director at a time?

Comment: In case there are two presidents or directors set as "current", I only want to retrieve the last entry to the database.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to achieve the results you want is to use [subqueries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions). So something like:

```
president_subquery = Position.objects.filter(
    organisation=OuterRef('pk'), position_type='president', position_current=True
).last()

director_subquery = Position.objects.filter(
    organisation=OuterRef('pk'), position_type='director', position_current=True
).last()

Organisation.objects.annotate(
    president=Subquery(president_subquery.values('person__fullname')),
    president_start_date=Subquery(president_subquery.values('position_start')),
    director=Subquery(director_subquery.values('person__fullname')),
    director_start_date=Subquery(director_subquery.values('position_start')),
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
Am I correct to add this to the OrganisationManager model? 
How do I call these annotated values in the template?

Comment: Yes you can put it in a manager if you need to. For templates, you can simply use them like how you use model fields. Like `{{ organisation.president }} - {{ organisation. president_start_date }}`